# Deleting a Request on a Facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook, request

I'm brand new to Facebook development, and I'm puzzling over the FB Requests documentation, wherein it claims:

"When a user is directed to your app by clicking accepting a Request you must delete the request after it has been accepted."

Quite frankly I have no idea what they're talking about.

How can I find my outstanding requests? What's the best way to go about deleting them (I'm using the Javascript SDK)? Are there any dire consequences to not deleting requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must delete the requests, and the [very next part of the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting) after the line you quoted explains how to do this with a direct API call, a javascript SDK example and a PHP example:

```
You can delete a request via the following methods:
```

### Deleting Requests

When a user is directed to your app by clicking accepting a Request you **must** delete the request after it has been accepted. Requests are not automatically deleted once they have been clicked, thus it is the **developer’s responsibility** to clear them once they have been accepted.

You can delete a request via the following methods:

#### Graph API

Issue an HTTP DELETE request to the concatenated `request_id`:

```
DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/[<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>]?
      access_token=[USER or APP ACCESS TOKEN]
```

#### JavaScript SDK

```
function deleteRequest(requestId) {
  FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Here is a full PHP sample which shows you how to concatenate the request_id and user_id in order to delete the outstanding requests for a user.\

//snipped the big PHP sample

Comment: Right. I saw that. Read that several times and just didn't get any of it, I'm afraid...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand then, after the user comes to your app and you've shown them the UI for whatever request they accepted, you need to delete that request from the API so it isn't still displayed in their facebook list of requests